# Javascript not loading when scraping using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape steamdb.info to download graphs of their apps that they have made. When I go to a games graphs using my normal browser, the graphs will load. However, when I use selenium, the graphs do not load, and they say "Javascript must be enabled". I think that this website can tell that I am using a bot and won't load the javascript. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pandas as pd
import time
from random import randint

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
#fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2);
#fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
#fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/home/brianebrahimi/Desktop/steamdb_info_scraper/output/")
#fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
#fp.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
#fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
fp.set_preference("javascript.enabled", True)
fp.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "brianebrahimi")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = fp)
driver.maximize_window()



start_url = "https://steamdb.info/apps/"

driver.get(start_url)

games_set = set()
while driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='Next Page']"):
    for game in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr"):
        time.sleep(randint(5,8))
        if game.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]/a").text not in games_set:
            game_app_id = game.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]/a").text
            games_set.add(game_app_id)
            game.find_element_by_xpath("//td[2]/a").click()
            time.sleep(randint(5, 8))
            try:
                #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id = 'tab-graphs']")
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id = 'tab-graphs']").click()
                time.sleep(randint(5,20))
                for download in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='highcharts-menu-item']"):
                    if download.text == "Download CSV":
                        download.click()
            except:
                driver.get(start_url)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='Next Page']").click()
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get these graphs to load?

Comment: Have you tried using a chromium browser? JavaScript must be enabled error is usually seen in JS-based framework fromtends such as react. I think the Firefox driver is not enabling Js which causes the frontend to not render

Comment: @nimishxotwod thank you for your answer! I tried using chrome and it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try [undetected_chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) if you think you are being detected as a bot.